# How to add the hyperlink in the IBM watson response node

Tags: ibm-watson

I am using the Watson Chat Assistant and integrated it through API to the Sales IQ. I want to include a hyperlink in the response node as created in the Watson Chat Assistant. I have included a [code](https://prnt.sc/u1r7yg) for the hyperlink in the JSON editor as provided in the response node.

The code works fine when i run the chat assistant through Watson "Try it" feature, see the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/u1r5de)

However, when i test in the SalesIQ chat box, it throws out as plain text. Please see the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/u1r92e).

Please help me fix the code so that it shows as the hyperlink in the SalesIQ chat bot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SalesIQ chatbox but I think it is not interpreting the HTML code. Look at the SalesIQ documentation on how to include links in the chat and use this in your response text.

Answer (score 0):

Zobot in SalesIQ doesn't support html in replies. However, you can use markdown to display hyperlink, as shown below.

[image]

And as an alternative to this, zobot has link widget exclusively to display links with icon and more control. [Help guide link](https://www.zoho.com/salesiq/help/developer-guides/deluge-widgets-links.html)